# SQLite: importing data from a DB to another with an "augmented schema"

Tags: database, sqlite, import, export, schema

First, let me clarify what I mean with "augumented schema".
I have DB_OLD with schema_old
Then DB_NEW with schema_new which is exactly the same as schema_old but for these features:

- Some new tables might have been added
- Some old tables might have been an increased number of columns

Saying it in another way, schema_new is built to contain all the informations contained in schema_old and some more (both for the tables and the columns)

Now to import the data I might do:

```
ATTACH 'dbfile_old' AS db_old;
INSERT INTO nametable SELECT * FROM db_old.nametable;
```

And this apparently works quite fine.
But I wonder if there is a way to import all the tables with a single command instead of inserting them one by one.
And, of course, if there is some hidden problem with this procedure that I cannot see right now (keeping in mind that I'm fine with the added columns being filled with {null} values).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in SQLite or `sqlite3` command that inserts into multiple tables at once.

You have to write your own code to iterate over the tables.

Comment: Ok, at least I won't waste more time looking for a thing that doesn't exist. Thanks. :)